# Using Python type hinting, how can I indicate that a function returns an equivalent or identical value to its input?

Tags: python, identity, type-hinting, python-typing

Is there any official way, using Python's type hinting system, to indicate that a function returns an equivalent or identical value to its input?

I know that type hints are typically not concerned with *values*, but it would be useful to have value typing for the specific case of "function returns its input or something `==` to its input".

What I'm hoping for is something like a `TypeVar`, but which also contains information reflecting on the signature of the annotated function (with at least some official support in e.g. PyCharm/MyPy/etc.), similar to this:

Identity:

```py
from typing import Identity

# Identity[0] indicates "returns the positional argument at index 0".
# Identity['foo'] would indicate "returns the kwarg named 'foo'".
def foo(arg1, arg2) -> Identity[0]:
    return arg1

foo(object())  # Passes type checking
foo(1)  # Fails type checking, as "is" identity won't work on all ints
```

Equivalence:

```py
from typing import Equivalent

def foo(arg1: int) -> Equivalent[0]:
    return (arg1 - 1) + 1
```

`Equivalent` is largely a no-op, other than validating that its parameters make sense given the function signature.

Does such a thing exist? If not, is it feasible or misguided?

#### What I have tried

`TypeVar` doesn't quite do what is needed here; it can indicate that the output type is the same as the input type, but doesn't concern itself with values.

I understand that value-constraining type systems are complex and not supported in Python, but am wondering if an exception has been made for the specific case of equal/identical return values.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what problem you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: What is _"'is' identity won't work on all ints"_ supposed to mean? `is` works exactly the same for _all_ objects. It sounds like you're thinking of interning, but that's irrelevant as far as `is` is concerned.

Comment: Problem I'm trying to solve: indicate to code-readers and type checkers that methods return the exact value they receive, for one or both of two definitions of "exact" (`==` or `is`). This would be useful in that consumers could infer constraints on output values, similar to `Literal` constraining values; I think that information would be useful to many programmers.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```py
T = TypeVar('T')

def iden(x: T) -> T:
    return x
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that only indicates that the returned value is of the same *type* as the input value, but not that it is the *exact same value* as the input value.

Comment: oh, I see what you're looking for, now. This could be achieved with enums, if it makes sense for the use case